# Create a Hanging Bucket Effect (Handle Hooked on Rod)

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to create a hanging bucket effect, where the handle hooks on a rod and when the bucket falls, the handle stays hooked. I've tried almost every combination of Active, Passive and Active (unchecked dynamic) for each object, but cannot get the bucket to recognize that the handle is there. I've created the handle from a path and converted it to a mesh, so I'm wondering if that is the issue

Here is the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fgziSnjLwu51Opn54m7xZQz3ArsMaA1W/view?usp=sharing

Any help on how I can create this effect would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Are all three parts rigid bodies with Mesh collision switched on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the relative size of your wire and bucket meaning the physics has to be calculated very precisely.  I tried to set this up and had similar problems initially, and the the following steps fixed it for me:

1. Make sure the Centre of all of your objects is set to be near your geometry. (Object > transform > Origin to Geometry)
2. In Scene settings increase the 'Steps per second' (I went to 240FPS) (Scene> Rigid Body > Steps Per.
3. Make sure the 'Sensitivity' on the wire and the bucket are set to zero (or very close to) other wise the 'hole' in the bucket is effectively closed by the buffer this creates. (I think this is likely your problem, your objects are effectively starting 'inside' each other, and collisions are not detected if they start overlapping.

Set the Bucket and the Wire Like the below picture, and the thing it's hanging from exactly the same except untick 'Dynamic':

[image: rigid dynamic settings]

I get this:

[image: Swinging Bucket on Wire]

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I tried all of that above, but the handle doesn't catch the bucket. Also, when I tried to keep the cylinder as a mesh and uncheck dynamic, it doesn't catch the handle, but does when set to cylinder. Your model came out nicely... let me attach my file to the original question and maybe that would help find the error? I made the hole with a boolean modifier- maybe that was the issue?

Comment: Strangely, when I connected both the bucket and handle it worked nicely for the animation I was going for- along with the steps that you mentioned, so thank you Jeff! That worked for me!

Comment: @VictorRodriguez You marked this as answered, did you find the solution?  Having a  quick look at your file I wonder if the problem is that the bucket mesh has lots of overlapping pieces, rather than being a properly solid mesh.... that might confuse things

Comment: Yes, your initial suggestions about the calculations helped tremendously. I ended up using convex hull for the bucket on this particular animation and in a re-design using mesh, was able to get the hanging effect. Thanks again!